# SimpleDateFormat and Locale API in Java

Tags: java, locale, simpledateformat

I have the following piece of code, which I thought would work as per what the documentation promised, but it didn't!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMMM/dd",    // format str
                                               new Locale("gd",   // language = Scottish Gaelic
                                                          "UK",   // region   = UK
                                                          "scotland")); // variant = scotland
    fm.parse("2013/an Dàmhair/25");
}
```

Executing this (when it's put in a class with proper imports/declaration) will give the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013/an Dàmhair/25"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at Foo.main(Foo.java:15)
```

Could anyone tell me if this is a bug (and/or unsupported feature)?

The date string is clearly valid date string in the Gaelic language, and the variant/language is also properly set. (Otherwise, I would expect to get IllegalArgument or some thing like that).

Any suggestion how to fix it would be greatly appreciated, too.

Thanks,

Comment: Does the Locale actually know about the month names you're using? What happens if you *format* the current date with your date formatter?

Comment: Ah, good question. I'll check. Thanks

Comment: Ok, it's giving me a plain English string. But that is *WRONG*. English and Scottish Gaelic  are far from similar!

Comment: Okay, so do you have any indication that Scottish Gaelic is *supported* as a language? Is it present in `Locale.getAvailableLocales`?

Comment: Well, haven't found the docs that explicitly said that it is supported, but if Scottish Gaelic is *not* supported, should I not have got an "UnsupportedLocaleException" or something like that?

Comment: Scottish Gaelic is not a supported Locale in Java. 

AFAIK, You wont get any exception as there is no such exception in Java SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own [DateFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateFormatSymbols dateFormatSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols(new Locale("gd", "UK", "scotland"));
    // sorry I don't know the other months in Scottish Gaelic. Thus the numbers
    dateFormatSymbols.setMonths(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "an Dàmhair", "11", "12" }); 

    SimpleDateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMMMM/dd", dateFormatSymbols); 
    System.out.println( fm.parse("2013/an Dàmhair/25"));
}
```

I hope this is a solution for you

Comment: Ah, interesting. I guess that'd work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html), this locale is not supported.

Comment: Here is the version for Java 7: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html

Comment: A bit off topic, but does Java take requests from users to add some Locale? If so, would you happen to know how to file a request?